# Feeding JavaScript variables into form fields on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I've got this almost working but can't quite complete it. I have a jQuery datepicker on a reservation page that feeds into an "Arrival" field as mm/dd/yyyy. I am using JavaScript to split that into separate mm, dd, and yyyy values, and I am now trying to feed these values back into the Month, Day and Year fields on the form before the form is posted to a third-party processing site.

I can successfully assign values to these fields using JavaScript, but my challenge is making this happen *after* the submit button has been hit, since I need it to carry the date that the user selected.

To give you all the relevant pieces, here's my submit button:

```
<input type='submit' onclick='toProcess()' name="submitButton" id='submitButton'
value='Check Availability' />
```

Here's the function (that does run as it should when the Submit button is clicked) to take the date and split it into the three separate values:

```
function toProcess(){
    var date = document.getElementById("Arrival").value;
    var splitDate = date.split("/");
    var arrivalMonth = splitDate[0];
    var arrivalDay = splitDate[1];
    var arrivalYear = splitDate[2];
    return [arrivalMonth, arrivalDay, arrivalYear];
}
```

And here's where I take the returned values to create variables to feed back into the form:

```
var newDates = toProcess();
arrivalMonth = newDates[0];
arrivalDay = newDates[1];
arrivalYear = newDates[2];
```

Up to this point, everything works without any problem. By using alerts I've been able to see that the values are definitely feeding through up to this point. But I just haven't been able to get those values to now feed back into the form.

I'm trying to do so using this:

```
document.getElementById("Month").value = arrivalMonth;
document.getElementById("Day").value =  arrivalDay;
document.getElementById("Year").value =  arrivalYear;
```

And this approach works fine if I use variables that existed before the Submit button was hit. I just can't get the *new* values to work.

I suspect that the problem is that, while the function is being properly called by clicking the Submit button, the elements following it are not being executed then, since they're outside the function. I just haven't been able to figure out how to send those values back to the form fields from inside the function.

Have I explained that clearly? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you returning an array in the `toProcess` function?, also couldn't you just set the form field values in the `toProcess` function?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Admittedly still learning javascript, but I understood I needed to use an array to return more than one value from a function. Is this not the case?

I did initially try setting the fields' values from inside the function, but couldn't get it to work. I assumed it was because they were local rather than global variables. If there is a way to do it from inside, that would probably solve the problem.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/EamR7/

Comment: Thanks Musa. Yep, that's what I want. It's the same code that I had used initially when trying to feed the fields from inside the function. For some reason though, it works for your on Fiddle, but still doesn't for my form. I'm going through it now trying to see where it breaks down; will update things here soon. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, I'm still lost with what feels like all the right pieces, but I just cannot make this happen. 

Here is my full form, with everything else in there just in case something seemingly unrelated is creating the problem. Where am I going wrong? 

http://jsfiddle.net/alwayslearning/dg6rt/

Comment: In your fiddle you'll see a select menu with `Choose Framework` select `no wrap (head)` instead of `onLoad` this will give your `toProcess` function global scope. http://jsfiddle.net/dg6rt/9/

Comment: Thanks very much again, Musa. Yep, that solves the problem in Fiddle, but not on my site. If you could help me get through this one last step, how do I make that happen on the actual Website? What am I just not seeing here?

Comment: [Sending this comment again to properly link to the fiddles.]  I'm running this on a localhost while in development. I just put the entire page on fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/alwayslearning/cALUx/ so that you can see absolutely everything that's there, including the head. The form is being sent to the page I copied at http://jsfiddle.net/alwayslearning/E9d2k/ Thanks again, @Musa

Comment: I've tested both files on my localhost and they work. Try debugging it (press F12 for development tools\firebug(if installed)\dragonfly...)

Comment: GOT IT! Thanks very much, @Musa. I just couldn't see why this worked in Fiddle and for you, but not for me on my localhost. I ran the debugger in Chrome, and it told me there was a space after the curly bracket at the end of the function. Instead of being like it should be:

    }

It was actually this:

    } 

Looks identical, but there's a space after that curly bracket. Fiddle seems to have stripped it out when it loaded the script, but my text editor didn't. And believe it or not, that was all it took to shut down that function. As soon as I deleted that space, everything worked!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, your suggestions, and your patience, Musa, and your help too, @Namanyayg. I'll vote up the input you both gave. But Musa, you've just commented rather than given an answer. How do I send a few points your way?

Thanks again. Hopefully this helps someone else somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, on clicking the submit button, the output that you have ready is not being displayed in the desired field.

Could you make a fiddle out of it?

Also, one problem I faced when in the past was that I didn't realize that a submit button REFRESHES the page, therefore effectively removing any script use.

Comment: Thanks; am working through the fiddle now that Musa created, as noted above. Will get an update here soon, once I figure out what's going on.